# Sorting by ascending title

Tags: geonetwork, order, title

I have a problem sorting by title in ascending order in the search section of geonetwork.
I set the title as the default search order, and note the metadata correctly sorted by title. The only problem is that the sort is descending and I would like it ascending. I also tried to set the "Reverse" sort property but it doesn't change anything.
Am I wrong or is it a bug?